# How to override header Token with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have problem to override header token with AngularJS becauase already set with `AuthInterceptor`.

```
app.factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $window) {
 return {
   request: function (config) {

   config.headers = config.headers || {};
   if (localStorage.getItem("token")!=='') {
     config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token");
   }
   return config;
 },
};
});

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
});
```

I would access another third party URL where using another Token,but always failed, because Token back to current Token in `localStorage`. I have used `TransformRequest`, but not work too, what is best practice to solve the problem?

Comment: You could change your $http interceptor to only set the Authorization token for your local url.

Comment: thanks @NikolajDamLarsen can you give example code?

Answer (score 0):

You could check that the URL in the intercepted request is a URL that you want to pass an authorization token. For instance, if the URL to your own API always starts with `https://api.myapp.com`, you could do it like this:

```
app.factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $window) {

    var urlForAuthorization = 'https://api.myapp.com';

    return {
        request: function (config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};

            if (config.url.startsWith(urlForAuthorization) 
                && localStorage.getItem("token") !== '') {
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token");
            }

            return config;
        }
    };
});
```